# Getting element inside an element

Tags: jquery

Alright so I am trying to achieve something simple but it seems Its not working correctly. I am basically trying to get the value of the class thats inside the font awesome icon.

```
<div class='last_split'>
    <i class='fa fa-trash-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>
    <p style='display: none;' class='row_id'>".$row["ID"]."</p>
    <p style='display: none;' class='table_name'>".$txt."</p>
</div>
```

Now since there are many font awesome outputs like these, I need to find the one I clicked on. 
The problem I am facing now is simple, it doesnt return the value. It just returns an empty alert.

```
$(".fa-trash-o").click(function() {
    var id = $(this,".row_id").val();
    var table = $(".table_name").text();
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the contextual selector you're using is for finding one element within another, yet the `p` is not a child of the `i`, so it will not be found. Instead, you could use `siblings()`.

Secondly, `val()` is used on form elements to get their value. `p` elements do not have a value. Presumably you want to get the text, so `text()` is what you need instead. Try this:

```
$(".fa-trash-o").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).siblings('.row_id').text();
    var table = $(".table_name").text();
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Why not `.next()`?

Comment: `next()`, `siblings()`... plenty of ways to skin a cat.

Comment: Next time, you talk about skinning a cat, you are dealt with. Say "dog" not "cat"! `:D`

Comment: Yeah but theres another problem I face then, variable table returns double name. For example if the table name is "my_table" it will return "my_tablemy_table" altho inside the paragraph its set correctly

Comment: @TomislavNikolić I don't see how that's possible given your code sample. If there's another issue, please update your question to include that code, or start a new question about it

Comment: Ah using siblings tag fixed. Thanks a lot! Ill mark this question as the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next) at this context not [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find),

```
$(".fa-trash-o").click(function() {
 var id = $(this).next(".row_id").text();
 alert(id);
});
```

Also `.val()` is for input form elements, it will internally look for .value property. So we have to use `.text()` instead of that.

FYI : `$(this, "selector")` is similar to `$(this).find('selector')`

Answer (score 1):

So the `row_id` class is not technically inside of it but a sibling of it, you would want to target it like this:

```
$(this).next('.row_id).text();
$(this).next('.table_name).text();
```

Since they are both `<p>` tags you should grab the `.text` or `.html`, `.val()` only works on form elements like an input or textarea

Answer (score 0):

`var id = $(this,".row_id").val();` makes no sense and paragraphs do not have a value

The element you want is a sibling so you should be using `next()` and `text()`.

```
$(this).next().text()
```

or

```
 var id = $(this).siblings(".row_id").text();
 var table = $(this).siblings(".table_name").text();
```